# How to Split Exception.StackTrace and get only the last line

Tags: c#, split

I have for example such an Exception.StackTrace:

```
message:Generic error:    in Npgsql.NpgsqlClosedState.Open(NpgsqlConnector context)
in Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open()
in Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection)
in Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection)
in Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
in Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\C\myapp\Default.aspx.cs:riga 33 Failed to establish a connection to '10.1.1.1'.
```

But what I would like to have is only the last line of the StackTrace, that is:

```
in Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\C\myapp\Default.aspx.cs:riga 33 Failed to establish a connection to '10.1.1.1'
```

How can I split the StackTrace to get only this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you really need the context (entire stack trace) to determine what went wrong.  However, to get the last line

```
 using System.Linq;

 var lastLine = e.StackTrace.Split('\n').Last();
```

Where *e* is the `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a string, so split it by new lines and take the last element from the array?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Split()` method like

```
        string[] lines = str.Split('\n');
        lines[lines.Length - 1];
```